# QGIS buffer distance parameter

Tags: qgis, buffer, mercator, bng

This is very intriging, I don't remember having seen this before.

I am working with the Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Buffer tool in QGIS (2.8.6-Wien)

If operating in British National Grid projection, when buffering a road (the road is also EPSG:27700) using 5000m, I get 5km on each side of the road when measuring the buffer distance with the Measure line tool.

If operating in World Mercator, when buffering the same road but re-projected first (EPSG:3395), using the same 5000m, I get 2.5km on each side of the road, 5km in total. It shouldn't be 10km in total again?

Why the buffer tool is using the distance buffer differently, depending on the projection. and which one is incorrect?

Comment: I strongly suggest you update your QGIS to the current LTR 3.10.

Comment: Don't use Web Mercator for anything involving measurements, living at 50+N means the measurements are off by 50% or so as you have seen

Comment: sorry if I didn't explain my self accurately, I was using 3395, World Mercator, not Web Mercator

Comment: EPSG:3395 only introduces the ellipsoidal eccentricity of the WGS84 geoid to the otherwise equal transformation (i.e. EPSG:3857 -> sphere | EPSG:3395 -> spheroid); the resulting dilation is almost the same, so @IanTurton's comment still stands correct.